# Using Lookup and SUM within Matrix Report using SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Using SSRS 2016 and have inserted a Matrix Report table show / calculate the monthly rate and the total. The monthly rate derived by a `LookUp` field which looks up the `PoolCar` and fetches the `Daily_Cost` from a different `DataSet` and then multiplied by the `Days` value field:

```
= Lookup(Fields!PoolCar.Value, Fields!Registration.Value, Fields!Daily_Cost.Value, "PoolCar_Costs") * Sum(Fields!Days.Value)
```

However, calculating the `sum()` of that column does not work.
Any ideas?

I tried to use the Variable option but it does not allow aggregations.

Update:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that you have testing the lookup function by itself to make sure it returns the expected value? as well the sum by itself in the same section of the report?

Comment: If the answer to the above is yes and they just don't work together, are you able to modify the sql query of the report?

Comment: @Pants answer is yes, the `Lookup` and the `Sum()` are on same report. However the `DailyRate` is from a different DataSet hence why I used the lookup function ... which fetches the values and calculates Days * DailyRate but now how do I sum-up to show total money spend :)

Comment: @Pants the SSRS fetches the info from the sharepoint list and the query type is <RSSharePointList xmln:xsi="....">

Comment: Also, adding a new Field (via Dataset Properties, does not work because it does not allow aggregates as an expression. `"The expression used for the calculated field 'MonthlyCost' includes an aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous or lookup function. Aggregate, RowNumber, RunningValue, Previous and lookup functions cannot be used in calculated field expressions."`

Comment: In your post you use `Fields!Daily_Cost.Value` but in your comment you call the field `DailyRate`. Ill ask this again. Have you confirmed that the Lookup formula works **by itself** before you try to multiple the sum?

Comment: @Pants sorry, my comment was just to make it sound more logical! Yes it is the `Fields!Daily_Cost.Value` and as per your question: no I have not configured anything, all I did was added the other DataSet and used the `Lookup` function. I have added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited (See code you call in the expressions(Detials Section)):**

You can do this many ways. Either do the sum in the query phrase builder...

**SQL**:

```
SELECT T1.*,
(SELECT Sum(S1.Daily_Cost) FROM YourTableName S1 WHERE S1.Registrations = T1.PoolCar) AS SumYouWantToCalculateBeforeTheReport
FROM YourTable T1
```

...or you can do this with custom code.

This solution requires your tablix to have a details section, where you pass the value of the field you want to sum every detail row, then you display/use the sum in the footer section with your calculation

**Code you call in the expression(Details Section)**

```
=Code.ValueIWantToSum(Lookup(Fields!PoolCar.Value, Fields!Registration.Value, Fields!Daily_Cost.Value, "PoolCar_Costs"))
```

**Code you call in the expression once the details section is done(Group Footer)**

```
=Code.DailyCostSum()
```

**Custom Code**

```
Private runningtotal As Decimal = 0

Function ValueIWantToSum(svalue As Decimal) as String

    runningtotal = runningtotal + svalue
    Return "added"

End Function


Private DailyCostSum() As Decimal
    Return runningtotal
End Function
```

Comment: I have tried to get this Custom Code sorted but I fail to understand the concept ... can you assist? the expression for Details Section, is it the one I am using to lookup `=Code.ValueIWantToSum( Lookup(Fields!PoolCar.Value, Fields!Registration.Value, Fields!Daily_Cost.Value, "PoolCar_Costs") * Sum(Fields!Days.Value) )` because this does not work ..."There is an error on line 30 of custom code: [BC30689] Statement cannot appear outside of a method body/multiline lambda."

Answer (score 0):

After endless hours, I came across [this website](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f313b397-3237-4974-afa6-f14f5a4cf2c9/ssrs-reportitems-total?forum=sqlreportingservices) where it explains in more details.
The important bit, which I figured out at the end, is that the column where the expressions are used, should be outside the grouping!

The following code has been added to the Code section in Report Properties.

```
Public Shared Value as Double=0
  Public Shared Function GetValue(Item as Double) as Double
     value= value + Item
     return Item
  End Function
  Public Shared Function GetTotal()
     return value
  End Function
```

The Data Row has the following expression:

```
=Code.GetValue( Sum(Fields!Days.Value) * Lookup(Fields!PoolCar.Value, Fields!Registration.Value, Fields!Daily_Cost.Value, "PoolCar_Costs") )
```

Whilst the total row has got the following expression:

```
=Code.GetTotal()
```

Comment: The drawback of this is that the totalValue is not refreshed when you for example use the parameters to show results for particular dates! Somehow, it adds the value on top of it instead of refreshing the result ... any ideas anybody?

Comment: @Pants the above CODE works for me, the only problem is that - when refreshing the report, it doubles the `Sum()` and also when selecting different dates via the parameters.... that is very strange. I suspect there is no 'refresh' parameter in the code?